# What is this plugin for redmine?

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

On lighthttp redmine, there is a git like downloadable links :
http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd2/repository

Also here :
https://projects.kde.org/projects/calligra/calligra-history/repository

What is the plugin used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the Redmine Checkout plugin by Holger Just.

http://dev.holgerjust.de/projects/redmine-checkout/wiki